# Javascript if statement firing past condition using jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a memory game and trying to figure out why my if statement in the clickMe() function continues to fire on another click. I feel like it may have to do with my click function but I haven't been able to work out why or how to remedy it yet.

What I'm trying to do is send a card to the opened array on click. When there is less than 1 in the array, the first if statement should fire. When there is more than 1 in the array the second if statement should fire. Only the first one seems to continually go off even if there is more than one item in the opened array.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help!

Update:

I figured it out! :) For anyone else that might pop by, all I had to do was put the click listener outside of the if statement and that fixed it up. Whoops. Thanks to whoever posted and later deleted their answer, got me on the right track!

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var symbols = ["diamond", "paper-plane-o", "anchor", "bolt", "cube", 
"anchor", "leaf", "bicycle",
"diamond", "paper-plane-o", "anchor", "bolt", "cube", "anchor", "leaf", 
"bicycle" ];
var opened = [];
var deck = $('.deck');

// Initialize Game
function createBoard() {
shuffle(symbols);
 );
for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    deck.append($('<li class="card"><i class="fa fa-' + symbols[i] + '"></i>
</li>'));
}
    clickMe();
};

function clickMe() {
  if (opened.length < 1) {
// When user clicks on the CSS class card click function fires
    $('.card').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var select = $this.context.innerHTML;
        opened.push(select);
        alert(opened.length);

});
} else if (opened.length >= 1) {
     alert("Else if!");
}
}

createBoard();
```

Comment: You're forgetting to check if `opened.length == 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page loads, the array has zero elements and that's why it never runs `else` statement. After populating the list, add click handler.

```
function createBoard() {
    //Other code here...
    attachClickHanlder();
};
```

Your `if` statement should be inside your click event handler because you want to check the size of the array after user clicks, not when the page loads.

```
function attachClickHanlder() {
    $('.card').click(function () {
        if (opened.length <= 0) {
            alert(opened.length);
        } else {
            alert("Else if!");
        };
        opened.push(this.innerHTML);
    });
}
```

```js
        var symbols = ["diamond", "paper-plane-o", "anchor", "bolt", "cube", 
                "anchor", "leaf", "bicycle",
                "diamond", "paper-plane-o", "anchor", "bolt", "cube", "anchor", "leaf", 
                "bicycle" ];
        var opened = [];
        var deck = $('.deck');

        // Initialize Game
    function createBoard() {
        for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
            deck.append($('<li class="card"><i class="fa fa-' + symbols[i] + '"></i></li>'));
        }
        attachClickHanlders();
    };

function attachClickHanlders() {
    $('.card').click(function () {
        if (opened.length <= 0) {
            alert(opened.length);
        } else {
            alert("Else if!");
        };
        opened.push(this.innerHTML);
    });
}
        createBoard();
```

```css
li {
            list-style: none;
        }
        .fa {
            font-size: xx-large;
        }
        .fa-diamond:before {
            content: "\2660";
        }
        .fa-paper-plane-o:before {
            content: "\2661";
        }
        .fa-anchor:before {
            content: "\2662";
        }
        .fa-bolt:before {
            content: "\2663";
        }
        .fa-cube:before {
            content: "\2662";
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:console.log(opened);" value="console show array" />
<ul class="deck"></ul>
```

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did after you posted earlier - it got me thinking about it, thank you so much for clarifying! works great now :)